# Is it possible to render a tableview 'skewed'?

Tags: ios, swift2, tableview

I'm coding in Swift 2.0 for devices running iOS7+.

Is it possible to present a tableview in a skewed/diagonal/slanted format as indicated below?

[image: Skewed TableView]

Obviously if the answer is yes, what process would I need to go through to get the result?

Comment: You can do it (not sure if you _should_ though) by providing a transform to the tableView. Something like [warning: just a silly random example]: `tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-0.2))` (or a `CATransform3D` to its layer)

Comment: thx @Alladinian will check this out though I think Duncan's comment below might render this unsuitable for me due to the taps issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Views in iOS have a transform property, of type `CGAffineTransform`. You can use that to make the view appear skewed. I don't know offhand how to create a transform that creates the skewing effect. I suggest doing some google searching.

The next issue you will face is interacting with taps. Changing the transform of a view does not transform the coordinate system applied to taps, so taps will still land on the non-skewed views. That will be much harder to sort out, and without doing a fair amount of research I don't have an answer for you on that one. (It would probably be possible to intercept touch events before they get to your table view and apply the inverse of your skewing transform to them so that you map the taps back to the rectangular coordinate system the table view is expecting.)

Comment: Thx Duncan - this is good to know for future reference however the taps issue highlighted does indeed open a can of worms I would have hoped to avoid so think some graphical 'faking' of a skew might have to be the compromise here - won't give the same overall effect but will save a fair amount of headache

Comment: I've decided to go with a CGAffineTransform since the skew in my case doesn't actually significantly displace any taps on the cell and i can 'reverse skew' any elements within the cell that should stay square on - if you can get your head round the maths involved in managing the transformation these things are pretty useful

Comment: You should be able to create a custom subclass of UITableView that skews the coordinates of tap events before passing them on to the UITableView ancestor class. I believe you'd apply the inverse of the view's CGAffineTransform to transform the tap coordinates.